# Superimposing a Figure onto Another Figure (two different colormaps)

Tags: matlab, graph

I have created two subplots for two different data sets. I was hoping to plot subplot(2,1,2) onto subplot(2,1,1), while keeping both colourbars to display the two sets of data.

Is there an efficient way to do this? I am somewhat of a novice at using MATLAB.

Comment: a minimal example is what is needed here. your code contains too many irrelevant lines to answer your question

Comment: we dont have `lon`, `lat`, `sevp` etc. it is not clear if what you want is a plot and an inset or something else....

Comment: @bla I have two data sets. The first data set is for subplot(2,1,1) and the second data set is for subplot(2,1,2). I want to know how to combine the two subplots, that is, plot the contours from subplot(2,1,2) onto subplot(2,1,1). Does that make sense?

Comment: so make up some fake data, and show a minimal working example of what you tried and where it failed.